# How can you keep the search from displaying the whole JSON database?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to learn how to work with searches. I have a few different versions I found, but they all have a similar problem. When you do a search of a JSON database and then you backspace or delete the search letters/words, it will show the entire JSON file. I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent this so if you backspace, remove a search word, or delete the search it won't display anything like when the page is initially loaded? I'd love to understand how to fix this issue because I think I could figure out the rest of the project I'm working on if this works. The HTML and Javascript code I'm looking at is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Search HTML Table Data by using JQuery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  #result {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   max-width:870px;
   cursor: pointer;
   overflow-y: auto;
   max-height: 400px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   z-index: 1001;
  }
  .link-class:hover{
   background-color:#f1f1f1;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
   <h2 align="center">JSON Live Data Search using Ajax JQuery</h2>
   <h3 align="center">Employee Data</h3>   
   <br /><br />
   <div align="center">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Employee Details" class="form-control" />
   </div>
   <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
   <br />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
 $('#search').keyup(function(){
  $('#result').html('');
  $('#state').val('');
  var searchField = $('#search').val();
  var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
   // if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.location.search(expression) != -1)
    if (value.name.search(expression) != -1)
    {
     $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="'+value.image+'" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> '+value.name+' | <span class="text-muted">'+value.location+'</span></li>');
    }
   });   
  });
 });

 $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
  $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
  $("#result").html('');
 });
});
</script>
```

The JSON file is (none of the images work, but that's not relevant to the problem):

```
[
  {
    "name":"Angel Lewis",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/3/000/0d4/2f7/07a3d35.jpg",
    "location":"Seattle, WA"
  },
  {
    "name":"Justin Dean",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAIMAAAAJGExNTE4OWY4LWU4ODMtNDA2ZS1iNWI1LWNkYmIyOWMyMGQ5Zg.jpg",
    "location":"Muscatine, IA"
  },
  {
    "name":"Nora Blake",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/2/005/0b8/118/387e091.jpg",
    "location":"Seattle, WA"
  },
  {
    "name":"Russell Fox",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/2/000/084/26e/2d9e05b.jpg",
    "location":"Albuquerque, NM"
  },
  {
    "name":"Daryl Bradley",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/3/000/042/0ad/197566e.jpg",
    "location":"Buckeystown, MD"
  },
  {
    "name":"Benjamin Gonzales",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/8/005/0b2/1c9/2a423c1.jpg",
    "location":"Atlanta, GA"
  },
  {
    "name":"Viola Francis",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAASJAAAAJGMyMTUzN2EyLTExY2ItNDZiNS1hMTY1LTI4NDA2NDMwZmFkNg.jpg",
    "location":"Zanesville, OH"
  },
  {
    "name":"Reginald Benson",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/1/000/10f/3cc/275a407.jpg",
    "location":"Gilbert, AZ"
  },
  {
    "name":"Glenda Ray",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/8/005/0ac/1ca/07c25a2.jpg",
    "location":"Baltimore, MD"
  },
  {
    "name":"Paula Vargas",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/5/005/03e/073/36a5c47.jpg",
    "location":"Baltimore, MD"
  },
  {
    "name":"Mark Armstrong",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/5/005/010/09b/39b122d.jpg",
    "location":"Hallandale Beach, FL"
  },
  {
    "name":"Jaime Campbell",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAATUAAAAJDJkY2Q1Mzk0LTI1YzItNDFhNy04ZmQ0LWY3NzZlZTZlNGVmYw.jpg",
    "location":"Zanesville, OH"
  },
  {
    "name":"Mike Beck",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/2/000/01c/0d4/2b69e7c.jpg",
    "location":"Garner, NC"
  },
  {
    "name":"Ann Lowe",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/7/000/1f6/019/29cd853.jpg",
    "location":"Cabin John, MD"
  },
  {
    "name":"Ryan Wolfe",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/1/000/0bf/335/05a57f6.jpg",
    "location":"Los Angeles, CA"
  },
  {
    "name":"Dwayne Gutierrez",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/3/000/29b/028/2426536.jpg",
    "location":"San Jose, CA"
  },
  {
    "name":"Bill Burke",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/7/000/1bc/12e/1423106.jpg",
    "location":"Bakersfield, CA"
  }
]
```

Comment: Why would you not want to display anything if the user deletes a word or character, while there's still stuff in the input? Eg starting from `Benjamin Gonzales`, do you *really* want deleting `Gonzales` to result in the `Benjamin Gonzales` result not coming up? `Benjamin` is still in the input

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what I'm saying. Okay, lets say that JSON database had 5000 names. Lets also say your did a name search for "Ben" and then decided, wait, I don't want to find all the Ben employees, I want to find the Bob employees. If you delete Ben from your search box, it then displays ALL the names from the ENTIRE JSON database until you start typing something else. I'm trying to figure out how to prevent it from displaying the entire database when the search box is empty.

Comment: Making things not display when the search box is empty is easy, but I'm asking about the other cases you described - when someone removes a word or letter

Comment: Oh... I just wanted it to not show the results that were displayed when whatever keyword was there. So if I searched for Ben and Bob and then removed Bob, it would only show those with Ben in it. The bigger one is if all search words are removed it shouldn't just dump the whole database into the list. Right now, if you do two names, it doesn't even display the results with both names. :(

Comment: *if I searched for Ben and Bob and then removed Bob, it would only show those with Ben in it* This is already what happens currently. Eg if you type in `Ben|Reg`, both Ben and Reginold will come up. Then if you delete the `|Reg` part, only `Ben` comes up. See snippet below.

Comment: It does, but if you type a pipe or back up to the pipe, you'll notice it will still show the entire database until typing again. The other fix you mentioned works for the empty search field. Can this also be accomplished by adding something similar when it gets to the pipe separator?

Comment: Filter the array first, then see if the filtered length is equal to the original array's length

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm doing this wrong. It doesn't seem to work. Are you comfortable showing the whole script section?

Comment: I did - look at the answer below. The scripts are even runnable, they're not *only* plain text, so you can press "Run code snippet" to see them running as desired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208378/discussion-between-robert-and-certainperformance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before you retrieve the value from the input field, you clear the results. So, after you retrieve the value, if the trimmed value is empty, simply return early, and nothing will be displayed:

```
var searchField = $('#search').val();
if (!searchField.trim()) {
  return;
}
```

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "Angel Lewis",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/3/000/0d4/2f7/07a3d35.jpg",
    "location": "Seattle, WA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Justin Dean",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAIMAAAAJGExNTE4OWY4LWU4ODMtNDA2ZS1iNWI1LWNkYmIyOWMyMGQ5Zg.jpg",
    "location": "Muscatine, IA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Nora Blake",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/2/005/0b8/118/387e091.jpg",
    "location": "Seattle, WA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Russell Fox",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/2/000/084/26e/2d9e05b.jpg",
    "location": "Albuquerque, NM"
  },
  {
    "name": "Daryl Bradley",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/3/000/042/0ad/197566e.jpg",
    "location": "Buckeystown, MD"
  },
  {
    "name": "Benjamin Gonzales",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/8/005/0b2/1c9/2a423c1.jpg",
    "location": "Atlanta, GA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Viola Francis",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAASJAAAAJGMyMTUzN2EyLTExY2ItNDZiNS1hMTY1LTI4NDA2NDMwZmFkNg.jpg",
    "location": "Zanesville, OH"
  },
  {
    "name": "Reginald Benson",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/1/000/10f/3cc/275a407.jpg",
    "location": "Gilbert, AZ"
  },
  {
    "name": "Glenda Ray",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/8/005/0ac/1ca/07c25a2.jpg",
    "location": "Baltimore, MD"
  },
  {
    "name": "Paula Vargas",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/5/005/03e/073/36a5c47.jpg",
    "location": "Baltimore, MD"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mark Armstrong",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/5/005/010/09b/39b122d.jpg",
    "location": "Hallandale Beach, FL"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jaime Campbell",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAATUAAAAJDJkY2Q1Mzk0LTI1YzItNDFhNy04ZmQ0LWY3NzZlZTZlNGVmYw.jpg",
    "location": "Zanesville, OH"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike Beck",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/2/000/01c/0d4/2b69e7c.jpg",
    "location": "Garner, NC"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ann Lowe",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/7/000/1f6/019/29cd853.jpg",
    "location": "Cabin John, MD"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ryan Wolfe",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/1/000/0bf/335/05a57f6.jpg",
    "location": "Los Angeles, CA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Dwayne Gutierrez",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/3/000/29b/028/2426536.jpg",
    "location": "San Jose, CA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bill Burke",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/7/000/1bc/12e/1423106.jpg",
    "location": "Bakersfield, CA"
  }
];


$('#search').keyup(function() {
  $('#result').html('');
  $('#state').val('');
  var searchField = $('#search').val();
  if (!searchField.trim()) {
    return;
  }
  var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    // if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.location.search(expression) != -1)
    if (value.name.search(expression) != -1) {
      $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="' + value.image + '" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> ' + value.name + ' | <span class="text-muted">' + value.location + '</span></li>');
    }
  });
});

$('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
  $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
  $("#result").html('');
});
```

```css
#result {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 870px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.link-class:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<br /><br />
<div class="container" style="width:900px;">
  <h2 align="center">JSON Live Data Search using Ajax JQuery</h2>
  <h3 align="center">Employee Data</h3>
  <br /><br />
  <div align="center">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Employee Details" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
  <br />
</div>
```

If you also want to display no results when all employees would be displayed, filter the array first, then only display results if the filtered array's length is not equal to the original array's length:

```
  const peopleToShow = data.filter(({ name }) => pattern.test(name));
  if (peopleToShow.length === data.length) {
    return;
  }
  for (const value of peopleToShow) {
      $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="' + value.image + '" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> ' + value.name + ' | <span class="text-muted">' + value.location + '</span></li>');
  }
```

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "Angel Lewis",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/3/000/0d4/2f7/07a3d35.jpg",
    "location": "Seattle, WA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Justin Dean",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAIMAAAAJGExNTE4OWY4LWU4ODMtNDA2ZS1iNWI1LWNkYmIyOWMyMGQ5Zg.jpg",
    "location": "Muscatine, IA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Nora Blake",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/2/005/0b8/118/387e091.jpg",
    "location": "Seattle, WA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Russell Fox",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/2/000/084/26e/2d9e05b.jpg",
    "location": "Albuquerque, NM"
  },
  {
    "name": "Daryl Bradley",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/3/000/042/0ad/197566e.jpg",
    "location": "Buckeystown, MD"
  },
  {
    "name": "Benjamin Gonzales",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/8/005/0b2/1c9/2a423c1.jpg",
    "location": "Atlanta, GA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Viola Francis",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAASJAAAAJGMyMTUzN2EyLTExY2ItNDZiNS1hMTY1LTI4NDA2NDMwZmFkNg.jpg",
    "location": "Zanesville, OH"
  },
  {
    "name": "Reginald Benson",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/1/000/10f/3cc/275a407.jpg",
    "location": "Gilbert, AZ"
  },
  {
    "name": "Glenda Ray",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/8/005/0ac/1ca/07c25a2.jpg",
    "location": "Baltimore, MD"
  },
  {
    "name": "Paula Vargas",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/5/005/03e/073/36a5c47.jpg",
    "location": "Baltimore, MD"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mark Armstrong",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/5/005/010/09b/39b122d.jpg",
    "location": "Hallandale Beach, FL"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jaime Campbell",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAATUAAAAJDJkY2Q1Mzk0LTI1YzItNDFhNy04ZmQ0LWY3NzZlZTZlNGVmYw.jpg",
    "location": "Zanesville, OH"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike Beck",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/2/000/01c/0d4/2b69e7c.jpg",
    "location": "Garner, NC"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ann Lowe",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/7/000/1f6/019/29cd853.jpg",
    "location": "Cabin John, MD"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ryan Wolfe",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/1/000/0bf/335/05a57f6.jpg",
    "location": "Los Angeles, CA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Dwayne Gutierrez",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/3/000/29b/028/2426536.jpg",
    "location": "San Jose, CA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bill Burke",
    "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/7/000/1bc/12e/1423106.jpg",
    "location": "Bakersfield, CA"
  }
];


$('#search').keyup(function() {
  $('#result').html('');
  $('#state').val('');
  const searchString = $('#search').val().trim();
  if (!searchString) {
    return;
  }
  const pattern = new RegExp(searchString, "i");
  const peopleToShow = data.filter(({ name }) => pattern.test(name));
  if (peopleToShow.length === data.length) {
    return;
  }
  for (const value of peopleToShow) {
      $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="' + value.image + '" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> ' + value.name + ' | <span class="text-muted">' + value.location + '</span></li>');
  }
});

$('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
  $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
  $("#result").html('');
});
```

```css
#result {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 870px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.link-class:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<br /><br />
<div class="container" style="width:900px;">
  <h2 align="center">JSON Live Data Search using Ajax JQuery</h2>
  <h3 align="center">Employee Data</h3>
  <br /><br />
  <div align="center">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Employee Details" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
  <br />
</div>
```